# Laravel 5 contact form not working

Tags: php, forms, laravel, sendmail, contact-form

I don't have any errors but I did not receive any email from the form.

This is **the view** (reduced):

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'contact_store', 'class' => 'form', 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => false]) !!}

        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">

        <textarea id="texto" name="texto" class="form-control"></textarea>

        {!! Form::submit('enviar', ['class' =>'btn btn-primary']) !!}

        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

The **controller** with the two methods:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web;

use App\Http\Requests\ContactRequest;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('web.nosotros.escribenos.escribenos');
    }
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = array(
            'nombre' => $request->nombre,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'texto' => $request->texto,
        );

        Mail::send('web.emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
            $message->from($data['email']);
            $message->to('my_email@domain.com');
            $message->subject('web contact');
        });

        return view('web.nosotros.escribenos.escribenos', compact('data'));
    }
}
```

The view **web/emails/contact** is only the format of the email:

```
<h3>New message from the web!</h3>
<div>
    {{$texto}}
</div>
<p>from: {{ $email }}</p>
```

The **routes** in routes/web.php

```
Route::get('escribenos', ['as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'ContactController@create']);
Route::post('escribenos', ['as' => 'contact_store', 'uses' => 'ContactController@store']);
```

In **config/mail.php** I have:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mydomain.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 25),
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'webmaster@mydomain.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'webmaster'),
    ],
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
```

And finally in **.env**:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mydomain.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=webmaster@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=my_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

All seem to be well, I don´t have any error but I don´t receive any email either. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Check your spambox and if por t25 is open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test your emails you can utilize [mailtrap.io](http://mailtrap.io) and add the username/password etc into the .env settings.

Here is generally how I would set it out:

Controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

    public function sendEmail(Request $request)
        {
            $data = array(
                'nombre' => $request->get('nombre'),
                'email' => $request->get('email'),
                'texto' => $request->get('texto')
            );

            // php artisan make:mail sendMessage - this needs to be ran in terminal / cmd
            Mail::to(config('mail.from.address'))->send(new sendMessage($data));
        }

SendMail.php:

private $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $data = $this->data;
        return $this->view('web.emails.contact', compact('data'))
            ->subject('Web Contact')
            ->from(Input::get('email'));
    }
```

web/emails/contact.blade (basic example):

```
<p>
    Hey there {{ config('mail.from.name') }}
</p>
<p>
    You have an email from {{ $data['nombre'] }} - email address {{ $data['email'] }}
</p>
<p>
    {!! $data['texto'] !!}
</p>
```

`config('mail.from.name)` & `config('mail.from.address)` can be adjusted within `config/mail.php` or you can simply remove these and add your own name / email address.

Comment: Not really...
Read https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input the section *Retrieving Input Via Dynamic Properties*

Comment: It does not seem that this is the problem, the data does pick them up well. When I make a dd ($ data) the result is: `array: 6 [▼
   "name" => "Nature"
   "email" => "test@mydomain.com"
   "text" => "test"
]`
  Still I have tried it in the way you indicate and the result is the same, everything is fine but I do not receive the email.

Comment: @nature. I have heavily edited this for you as to the best way to do it and also more information on testing the mailbox by using mailtrap.io.

Comment: I see @Option I have to create a Mailable. I´m going to test it…

Comment: @nature, I strongly advise testing with mailtrap.io it's great for localhost email testing etc.

Comment: @nature, no problem at all.

Comment: Well I have the same result @Option. I don't receive any email. I'm supposed to receive the email in the mailtrap inbox, isn't it? I created the account in mailtrap.io I changed into `config/mail.php :   'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mailtrap.io'), 'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),`

Comment: and into .env `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=myusername
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166337/discussion-between-option-and-nature).

Comment: By the way, I suppose you were referring to sendMessage.php not sendMail.php

Comment: @nature, apologies I didnt make it back online in time to finish up! Glad you got it working with the `artisan cache:clear` command :-)

Comment: @Option it´s ok, you´ve helped me a lot. Thanks for everything.